# mysql root password forgotten

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, reset

I did not use PHP MySQL for quite a while and now I need to use it again. But the problem is I forget the password for the MySQL console. and getting error #1045 when trying to login in to PHPMyAdmin.

In the MySQL site I saw an article how to reset root password( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows)

Steps are

```
create a mysql-init.txt file containing UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I saved it as `C:\me\mysql-init`

and in command prompt I wrote--

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\me\mysql-init.txt
```

I tried with double backslashes also..but it is not working. MySQL console is asking for a password and it's not taking the new-one. What am I doing wrong? I have several tables there.what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://youtu.be/gFo5DV_pSg8 - This video helped me in changing password in one of my production servers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Comment: Make sure you're admin in the command prompt. I had to enclose my txt file with "". .\mysqld.exe --init-file="C:\MySQLDEV\my_init.txt"

Answer (score 40):

Here are the steps to be followed:

1. Locate the MySQL configuration file using: `$ mysql --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

[image]

On Ubuntu 16, the file location is typically `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

2. Edit the configuration file using: `$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
3. Add `skip-grant-tables` under `[mysqld]` block and save the changes.

[image]

4. Restart MySQL service using: `sudo service mysql restart`
5. Check MySQL service status: `sudo service mysql status`

[image]

6. Login to mysql with: `$ mysql -u root`
7. And change the `root` password:

> mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>
> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
>   mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass';

8. Revert back the MySQL configuration file changes by removing `skip-grant-tables` line or commenting it with a `#` (hash).
9. Finally restart the MySQL service and you are good to go.

Comment: life saving solution :)

Comment: For older versions of MySQL, e.g. for MySQL 5.5: the password change is  `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`

Comment: This should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 15):

I couldn't get `mysqld` in Adelave's answer to work.   But this worked for me instead

stop and  start mysql with --skip-grant-tables

```
service mysql.server stop
service mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
```

then connect to your mysqld without username/password

```
mysql
```

then update the password on mysql command line

```
 mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; 
 mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 mysql> \q
```

then restart mysql normally

```
 service mysql.server restart
```

Comment: This is applicable for MysQL 5.6.16 on Mac OSX 10.9.1, it works for me ;-)

Comment: The `start -skip-grant-tables` command throws a **ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file** error..

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to` on Mysql 8

Answer (score 13):

try to start mysql with --skip-grant-tables

> ```
> mysqld --skip-grant-tables
> ```

then connect to your mysqld without username/password using mysql command line

> `shell> mysql`

then issue command

```
> mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
>        WHERE User='root'; mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.It is working for the time being.Now I am able log in to phpmyadmin to copy all the tables that I want to save.THANK YOU.But it is not taking the password when I reopen the wamp server later.I have to go through the same process like mysqld --skip-grant-tables .

Comment: The version of mysql I have installed doesn't have a Password column instead this worked:
update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('MyNewPass') where User = 'root';

Comment: failed to set datadir to /var/lib/mysql/

Comment: If your sql version tells you it isn't "the right syntax to use near ('MyNewPass')" :
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass';`

Comment: "`Thank you very much for reply.It is working for the time being.`" - in which case, please accept the answer, which will help others who read this question in future

Answer (score 5):

If other answer could not help, you can try to uninstall/re-install mysql. It works on my ubuntu server:

```
$sudo apt-get purge mysql*
$sudo apt-get autoremove
$sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Update distribution

```
$sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And re-install

```
$sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Mac OS Mojave**

```sh
$ brew services stop mysql

$ pkill mysqld

// warning: deletes all tables
$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/

$ brew postinstall mysql

$ brew services restart mysql

$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'p4ssword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

Then you are back to normal for dev.

```sh
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

I don't like to see the word `root` in my `.env` files, so I usually do this after, if making a site such as `www.hockeysticks.net`:

```sql
#
CREATE DATABASE hockeysticks;

CREATE USER 'hockeysticks'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'hockeysticks';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON hockeysticks.* TO 'hockeysticks'@'localhost';
```

Then your localdev `.env` file is simple:

```sh
DB_DATABASE=hockeysticks
DB_USERNAME=hockeysticks
DB_PASSWORD=hockeysticks
```

**Note**: If you need to retain your databases, use the `skip-grant-tables` method. That has 3 hard parts:

1. Make sure MySQL is stopped, so you can restart it with `skip-grant-tables`
2. Make sure your password update SQL syntax is correct for your MySQL version
3. Make sure you append the end of the query with `FLUSH PRIVELEGES;`

Answer (score 3):

**Using windows command prompt you can change the password**

1. Go to `windows+R` and run `services.msc` and then stop the MySQL services and see the properties of MySQL by right click and copy the path  `--defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"` as it required later.
2. Create text file `reset.txt` with the text `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Your New Password';` and save in `C` drive.
   [image]
3. open the command prompt as administrator then change the directory where your MySQL is installed `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"`.
4. Type the command `mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\reset.txt`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in MariaDB 10.6.11

To do next mysql root login without password in shell

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Mysql root login

```
mysql -u root
```

Use mysql database

```
use mysql;
```

Create Authentication string for new password

```
SELECT PASSWORD('asdlfjasldfkjklasdkflasdjfla');
```

Output: *B1D04474F8D522B69410FC0E731B35ED22E94A3C

Now check priv for user root

```
select priv from global_priv where user='root';
```

Output: {"access":549755813887,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"*LEICHEI2THEIYUOCH3PEE5OOVU8UQU4B","auth_or":[{}],"version_id":100611,"password_last_changed":1677497088}

Update priv for user root with newly generated authentication_string

```
update global_priv set Priv='{"access":549755813887,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"*B1D04474F8D522B69410FC0E731B35ED22E94A3C","auth_or":[{}],"version_id":100611,"password_last_changed":1677497088}' where user='root';
```

Flush Privileges

```
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score -1):

### Using SQLYog you can execute commands

- User Creation

---

```
CREATE USER 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123#d'
```

- Authorization

---

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sakila.* TO 'tester'@'localhost'
```

- Changing Password in MySQL 8.0

---

```
ALTER USER 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123#d'
```

(or if u know the authentication_string directly set it to update)

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
    SET authentication_string='*F9B62579F38BE95639ACB009D79427F2D617158F'  
WHERE USER='root'***
```

Changing password in lower versions of mysql

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.\* TO 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123#d'
SET PASSWORD FOR 'tester'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('Pass123#d');**
```