# Root user not working on local MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, macos

There are several similar threads on this topic, but none of them seem to address my issue. I have a fresh install of MYSQL 5.6.11 on Mac OS 10.8. I was not prompted to create a root password during the install process. That should mean there is no password, or the password is root. However, I can't connect as root with any of these combinations, or my system password, or anything else.

As a result I get some version of this error for every command I run, including when I try to reset the root password:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I uninstalled MYSQL and reinstalled it. Same problem. I downloaded Sequel pro can can connect without any user or password set, but have no permission to do anything.

Comment: `mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass`

Comment: It gives me access denied error when I try this. I never set a password, so trying root, leaving it blank, and using my system password all result in access denied.

Comment: 'Freddie:data Greg$ mysqladmin -u root -p password root
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
Freddie:data Greg$ mysqladmin -u root -p password root
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: Try connecting as _mysql instead of root

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What about the method proposed here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564012/2244833 ?

Comment: I don't have permissions to stop or start MySQL: `Freddie:data Greg$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql stop
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'stop'
Freddie:data Greg$ `