# Mysql password expired. Can't connect

Tags: php, mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan

I just wiped my Mac and did a fresh install of El Capitan. I'm struggling to connect to Mysql now. Having gone through a web server setup process, I've created a simple PHP test file:

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "xxxxxxxx");
  if ($conn->connect_error) echo "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error; 
  else echo "Connected successfully";
  phpinfo();
?>
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1862): Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. in /Users/rich/Documents/DESIGN/test/index.php on line 3
Connection failed: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
```

I've never seen that response from a connection before. How do I fix it if I can't connect?

**EDIT**

In terminal I entered the command:

`mysql -u root -p`

This asked me for my password (current one) which I put in. I now have access to mysql commands but anything I try results in this error:

```
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
```

How do I reset the password using `ALTER USER`?

Comment: this is really annoying that a whole service can be shutdown because of this

Comment: Try running `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password`

Comment: @ConnorLeech spent hours trying to reset homebrew's MariaDB expired root password, but this fixed it for me - thanks!

Answer (score 186, accepted):

So I finally found the solution myself.

Firstly I went into terminal and typed:

`mysql -u root -p`

This asked for my current password which I typed in and it gave me access to provide more mysql commands. Anything I tried from here gave this error:

`ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

This is confusing because I couldn't actually see a way of resetting the password using `ALTER USER` statement, but I did find another simple solution:

`SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('xxxxxxxx');`

Comment: Did this work properly? Did it gave any error after following these steps in future?

Comment: I use version 5.7.9 of MySQL and this is now deprecated as this error message from MySQL command prompt tells us: Warning (Code 1287): 'SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('<plaintext_password>')' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET PASSWORD = '<plaintext_password>' instead

Comment: I am sorry this did not work for me but the alter user posted by Piotr N. worked. Perhaps operating on different version of MySQL.

Answer (score 99):

First, I use:

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Giving my current password for the 'root'.
Next:

```
mysql> ALTER USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password',
       `root`@`localhost` PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

Change `'new_password'` to a new password for the user 'root'.
It solved my problem.

Comment: Getting Error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newPassword','root'@'localhost' PASSWORD ' at line 1

Comment: This worked well. ALTER USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password',
       'user'@'%' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;

Comment: Getting error: 

```ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted```

Answer (score 53):

`mysqladmin -u [username] -p password` worked for me on OS X El Capitan and MySQL 5.7.12 Community Server. Example:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password
Enter password:
New password:
Confirm new password:
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
```

This is similar to pavan sachi's answer, but with password prompts.

My error was "#1862 - Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords." at phpMyAdmin login screen first time.

Comment: Worked for me too, OS X El Capital and MySQL 5.17.13! Thanks for this!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the word "password" is *not a placeholder*, whereas "root" is the name of the user you'd like to update: `mysqladmin -u [username] -p password`

Comment: This is the only thing that (seemingly) worked for me on Linux (Fedora 25). Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

### MySQL password expiry

Resetting the password will only solve the problem temporarily. From MySQL 5.7.4 to 5.7.10 (to encourage better security - see [MySQL: Password Expiration Policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html)) the default `default_password_lifetime` variable value is 360 (1 year-ish). For those versions, if you make no changes to this variable (or to individual user accounts) *all* passwords expire after 360 days.

So from a script you might get the message: "Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords."

To stop automatic password expiry, log in as root (`mysql -u root -p`), then, for *clients that automatically connect to the server* (e.g. scripts.) change password expiration settings:

`ALTER USER 'script'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;`

*OR* you can disable automatic password expiration for *all users*:

`SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;`

As pointed out by Mertaydin in the comments, to make this permanent add the following line to a `my.cnf` file MySQL reads on startup, under the `[mysqld]` group of settings. The location of `my.cnf` depends on your setup (e.g. Windows, or Homebrew on OS X, or an installer), and whether you want this per-user on Unix or global:

[mysqld]
`default_password_lifetime = 0`
(There may be other settings here too...)

See the [MySQL docs on configuration files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Comment: With an already expired password, only the global setting worked for me.

Comment: You can add this parameter to /etc/mysql/my.cnf, under mysqld; default_password_lifetime = 0
otherwise, after mysql restart you will get same error again.

Answer (score 11):

I went through the same issue recently while installing mysql on mac os x capitan.
I did not find the correct answer here, so adding this answer.

MySql in current versions, generates a temporary password when you install mysql. Use this password to set a new password using the mysqladmin utility as below;

> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p'<your temp password>' password '<your new password>'

Hope it helps you and others.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword','root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

Answer (score 7):

Just download MySQL workbench to log in. It will prompt you to change the password immediately and automatically.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows in phpmyadmin look in Variables: default_password_lifetime, and switch it to 0 (instead of 360), enjoy.

Its possible than mySQL take again 360 days, so add in my.ini :

```
[mysqld]
default_password_lifetime=0
```

And restart mysql.

Comment: Its possible than the default_password_lifetime take again 360 days, so in my.ini add :

Answer (score 4):

start MYSQL in safe mode

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Connect to MYSQL server

```
mysql -u root
```

run SQL commands to reset password:

```
use mysql;
SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Last step, restart your mysql service

Answer (score 4):

i have faced this issue few days ago. For best solution for 5.7 version of MySQL; login your mysql console and alter your password with the following command:

```
ALTER USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password', `root`@`localhost` PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

Answer (score 4):

***WARNING: this will allow any user to login***

I had to try something else. Since my root password expired and altering was not an option because

`Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted`

temporarly adding `skip-grant-tables` under `[mysqld]` in `my.cnf` and restarting mysql did the trick

Answer (score 2):

All of these answers are using Linux consoles to access MySQL.

If you are on Windows and are using WAMP, you can start by opening the MySQL console (`click WAMP icon->MySQL->MySQL console`).

Then it will request you to enter your current password, enter it.

And then type `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('some_pass');`

Answer (score 1):

restart MySQL server with --skip-grant-tables option
And then set a new root password

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Now if you need, you can update mysql.user table(field password_expired='N') not to expire the password.

Comment: When I enter the first command `mysql -u root` I get this error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: For the record i managed to get in by changing the first command to `mysql -u root -p` then it asked me for the password which I put in. Your next command didn't work for me because it said `You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Comment: Do you know how to reset the password using ALTER USER? I'm not that good with Mysql (I'm more of a NodeJS/MongoDB person).

Answer (score 1):

best easy solution:

```
[PATH MYSQL]/bin/mysql -u root
[Enter password]
SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;
```

and then works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

Source: https://www.diariodeunprogramador.net/fallo-al-conectar-mysql-your-password-expired/

Login as root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then you deactivate the automatic expiration of passwords of all the users:

```
SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

On DBeaver, Edit Connection -> Driver Properties -> disable disconnectOnExpiredPasswords:
[image]

Reconnect and:
[image]

And execute:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('NEW_USER_PASSWORD');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

The password expiration is a new feature in MySQL 5.6 or 5.7.

The answer is clear: Use a client which is capable of expired password changing (I think Sequel Pro can do it).

MySQLi library obviously isnt able to change the expired password.

If you have limited access to localhost and you only have a console client, the standard mysql client can do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've downloaded Sequel Pro and tried to connect via socket with that. I get the same error about the password being expired...

Answer (score 0):

Open MySQL console and type SET PASSWORD = 'your password'; 
and then press ENTER Key which will set your defined password for user root.

You can only write SET PASSWORD = '';
which will set password as blank for root user.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD(''), password_expired = 'N' WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```

Comment: `You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8.0 +, if you get this error,

```
    *Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that 
    supports expired passwords.*
```

you need use current user , to open mysql terminal, then use

```
SET PASSWORD ='123456'; To get a new password 123456 for current user;
```

Don't use `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('123456');` This one have been deprecated in MySQL 8.0+;

Answer (score -1):

Just open MySQL Workbench and choose [Instance] Startup/Shutdown and click on start server.
It worked for me