# Mysql error 1862 - Rookie answer

Tags: mysql

Im a rookie programmer and have been using mysql for the past 6 months. But all the sudden it reported a 1862 error and that my password was expired.

I have seen other answer to this. Such as: [Mysql password expired. Can't connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387879/mysql-password-expired-cant-connect) and [Mysql password expired. Can't connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387879/mysql-password-expired-cant-connect). But since im essentially a newcomer to mysql (besides sql statements), I have no idea what to do.

I have read to you can just write:
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('XXXXXXXXXXX') 
And that would fix the problem. But I have no idea where to write this or how to acces it.

Please help

Comment: Do you have access to the `root` account? If not, time for rescue mode.

Comment: I believe that the account has root access, yes. But it will not let me acces the database or any sql-scripting. + I can't start up mysql command line. It chraches after I enter the password.

Comment: If it's the literal `root` account and you're locked out, you need to restart with permissions checking turned off ("rescue mode").

Comment: Have do I do that?

Comment: It's not a Stack Overflow question because this isn't programming and it's been answered a billion times before. Search "mysql recover root password".

Comment: But (also for future reference) how do I acces programes, that allow me do this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html.
And thanks for helping anyway

Comment: If your MySQL server is operated by a commercial hosting service or a company IT department, contact them for help on this.

Comment: Unfortunnally It's not the case. But thanks for the answer anyhow.