# Laravel Homestead Cannot Connect to MySQL from host

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, virtual-machine, homestead

I saw many threads on forums and Stackoverflow about this issue but none were addressing in a way that worked for me.

I used the following credential on my host computer (using Sequel Pro) to log in homestead MySQL as documented:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
username: homestead
password: secret
```

It says that "**Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out**".

I then tried to log using ssh:

```
MySQL host: 10.0.2.15
Username: homestead
Password: secret
Port: 3306

SSH host: 192.168.10.10
SSH user: vagrant
SSH Password: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I got "**Connection failed: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.**"

Answer (score 2):

I then followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387879/mysql-password-expired-cant-connect) to change my password.

```
homestead ssh
mysql -uhomestead -psecret
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('secret');
```

That fixed my problem as I was now able to connect from ssh as described above.