# Mysql stuck in an expired password loop

Tags: mysql-5.7

I can no longer connect to my databases with `mysql 5.70.20` on `macOS 10.13.1` as I get the following message.

`Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.`

Now, this would seem like an easy [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387879/mysql-password-expired-cant-connect). But unfortunately I think im stuck in a loop.

Here is what I am trying. `mysql -u root` this works as expected. After connecting im trying `ALTER USER 'script'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;` which gives me an `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

After the previous I tried `SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;` which printed `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)` this als did not fix the problem as nothing was affected.

Then I tried `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('root');` which printed `ERROR 3009 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. Created with MySQL 50718, now running 50720. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.`.

So I try to run what it is recommending me `mysql_upgrade` and this puts me back to where I was `mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1862: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. while connecting to the MySQL server Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.`

Comment: I do not know if that works. But try to make a new user with new password and admin-privilegs. Then change or delete the old one...

Comment: @ratmalwer I can't ```mysql> CREATE USER 'new'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new';
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.```

Comment: Export your Tables - create a new DB - hopfully that works!!

Comment: @ratmalwer The data isn't of any importance luckily. So I tried to reinstall it ```brew uninstall --force mysql``` followed by ```brew install mysql``` which did not work. creating a new database also does not work it :/

Answer (score 1):

Solution worked for me on Ubuntu is complete removal of mysql:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This will also remove system tables so you can start from scratch.
Can someone translate this to macOS?