# Cannot start mysql 5.7 in MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-5.7

I installed mySQL using Homebrew and used it without password. But when I tried to access again it returned,

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/my.cnf' is ignored.
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

when using without the password. And returned

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/my.cnf' is ignored.
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

when using the password.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: try these steps https://www.programering.com/a/MTM1kjMwATc.html

Comment: @RahulVyas It returned .Logging to 
`'/var/lib/mysql/Nethminis-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2019-11-25T07:21:34.6NZ mysqld_safe Directory '/var/lib/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`

Comment: it is already answered here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339513/access-denied-for-user-root-mysql-on-mac-os