# MySQL Root Password Reset Not Working on Windows 7

Tags: mysql

I followed the mysql 5.6 manual's instructions to reset my root password, but it is not working.  I also tried using the '--skip-grant-tables' option based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070401/mysql-root-password-forgotten).  Still not working.

I am using windows 7 and MySQL 5.6, it is running as a service.  Here is exactly what I did:

First, I did steps 1 to 5 from [this procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html), to stop the MySQL service, and create my init file.  This is my init file, with the password censored:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('**********') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I also checked the properties on my service, and it does have the correct path to MySQL5.6

Then in a new terminal did this:

```
C:\Users\michael>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --init-file=C:\Users\michael\mysql-init.txt --skip-grant-tables
2014-10-13 10:18:10 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

After that, the terminal was no longer usable, I could not do ctrl+c, nor type anything.  So I opened a new terminal and tested logging in with that password, it worked.

At that point it was not running as a service.  The only way I could think of stopping mysqld was by using the task manager, since ctrl+c in the terminal was not working, and closing the terminal did not stop mysqld.  After I stopped it from the task manager, I went back to my services window and started mysql as a service.

Unfortunately though, I tried logging in again, using the same password that worked moments ago, and I am still being denied access:

```
C:\Users\michael>mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

what am I missing?

Comment: why the down vote?  why the vote to close?  This is not a duplicate, I searched for similar questions and could not find an answer.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled all MySQL products, and tried to reinstall MySQL.  The installer failed when attempting to set my root user password.  I left the current password field blank in the installer window, and provided a new root password.  So reinstalling MySQL did not solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, can anyone help us please? These steps for Windows, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html, also give the same "timestamp with implicit default value is deprecated" error.

Comment: Hey did you figure this out?

Comment: Is there a reason you combined the windows instructions with the B.3.3.2.3 "General" instructions?  Have you tried with just the ini file and not also --skip-grant-tables ?