# phpMyAdmin password reset

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, nas

I am running a ReadyNAS 102 and installed MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin to setup a database for use with OwnCloud. The first install was successful, but after forgetting some login passwords I decided to go for a full reinstall of the above.

Now, when opening phpMyAdmin, I get the following message:

> #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I understand from other sites that I need to access the config.ini.php file to edit the user details manually (and reset the root), however I have no idea how to access this file on the NAS. Is there a command line access for files on the NAS?

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/

Comment: you should have command line access on the nas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql root password forgotten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070401/mysql-root-password-forgotten)